# Ошибка Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Пытаюсь открыть на сайте во фрейме другую страницу. Использую для этих целей fancybox. Но после запуска выдаёт такую ошибку Refused to display 'имя сайта' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

```css
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.fancybox').fancybox();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><a >Iframe</a></li>
    <li><a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="сайт">Iframe</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/same-origin-policy

Comment: как исправить то?

Comment: Дайте разрешение на доступ на том сайте куда вы пытаетесь попасть со страниц своего сайта.

Comment: Visman, я изменил запусаемую страницу во фрейме, вместо сайта у которого путь был на другой домен, я поставил страницу текущего сайта, но ошибка осталась

Comment: Возможно ваш сайт возвращает вообще заголовок `x-frame-options 
deny`, но вероятнее всего вы где то ошибаетесь. Откройте инспектор сети в вашем браузере, перезагрузите страницу и посмотрите какие запросы куда уходят и какие ответы возвращаются.

Comment: Удалось ли решить проблему? У меня похожая ситуация, не выводится в фрейме окно телеграма `Refused to display 'https://t.me/joinchat/mySite' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'`.